# Integrating Mmenu plugin to Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, mmenu

How to integrate a mmenu jQuery plugin in Vue.js?
I plugged in the mmenu in index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/7.0.1/jquery.mmenu.all.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/7.0.1/jquery.mmenu.all.js"></script>
```

So, as a result it's included in the whole project. But, I can't use it in my Vue component. I initialized the **mmenu** plugin in `created()` method:

```
created() {
    $('#menu').mmenu();
}
```

And the markup:

```
<a href="#menu">Menu</a>
<!-- The menu -->
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/">Home</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/about">About</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/contacts">Contact us</router-link></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But it doen't seem to work. What do I have to do in order to make it work in a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

If someone still be interested, I solved it this way:

```
<template>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
        <a href="#menu">
            <span></span>
        </a>
        <nav id="menu">
            <!-- menu list to insert here -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'mmenu-js/dist/mmenu.css'
import 'mmenu-js/dist/mmenu.js'

export default {
    mounted() {
        new Mmenu(document.querySelector('#menu'))

        document.addEventListener('click', evnt => {
            let anchor = evnt.target.closest('a[href^="#/"]')
            if (anchor) {
                // Go somewhere
                evnt.preventDefault()
            }
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check that there are no javascript errors in the console. Then, with the help of the manual, try using the API `open()` method to open the panel. I think it's not just Vue.js

Comment: Please edit your answer and change it to English please.